# Trouble with overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a container element with the "overflow-y: hidden" attribute. However, this makes the "overflow-x" property become "scroll" instead of visible. I have no way to make it overflow x-: display. Have any way to make its "overflow-x" property is "visible" while keeping "overflow-y: hidden"?

```css
 .container{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    
  }
  .container div{
    background-color: red;
    width: 120%;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div>
     overflow x div
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Mido, I'm having trouble to understand the problem. What do you mean by "overflow-x" property is "visible".

Comment: What if you add overflow: visible; after overflow-y: hidden;?

Comment: @VivekrajKR I want "overflow-x: visible" for container div

Comment: @FabioAssuncao I tried but it didn't work

Comment: @Mido Ok. But why are you giving width 50% to container and width: 120% to child div. Can you please elaborate on the desired result with jsfiddle.

Comment: @ VivekrajKR You can imagine how a dropdown-menu displays with submenu. 50%  for main menu and 120% represent for side sub menu, it must be display outside the main menu.
I could not produce the result I wanted, that was the problem I encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try max-height property ?

```css
 .container{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: visible;

    
  }
  .container div{
    background-color: red;
    width: 120%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div>
     overflow x div
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It cannot solve the problem I'm having. I. However it actually solved this example problem.
I am using a container with max-height attribute. And the max-height of a child div does not work with ancestral elements that use the maxi-height instead of the height

Answer (score 0):

Change the width in the container to either 100% or fixed px

Comment: This isn't my problem. I want child div width overflow and it can be displayed.

Comment: i see, I assume you must have this hidden? as   
 overflow-x:visible; will make the container div visible, or    overflow-x:visible;
      overflow-y:hidden; on the container div.
Not entially sure what you're looking for .Hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I need overflow-x: visible and overflow-y: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I made this at chrome and it worked.

https://jsfiddle.net/fz7mt3ho/

css

```
 .container{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow: visible; /*added line*/
  }
  .container div{
    background-color: red;
    width: 120%;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: This makes both overflow-x and overflow-y is visible